# In restful url design, is it good that reusing url?

Tags: web-services, restful-url

There is a one restful url like,
**http://www.somedomain.com/cars/12**

The url is shared to many people.
And someday the car 12 is removed and the url is 404.

And the number 12 is reused to another car.
So the url isn't 404 now, but it is different to previous car.

I wonder this situation is ok, because this url was shared before the car is changed.

People may see another car that the sharer want to share before.
That is incorrect information.

thanks for help!

Comment: It depends on what the `12` signifies and whether other external entities refer to it. Is `12` supposed to be the unique identifier of *that* specific car? Then you shouldn't reuse it. Or is it the "12th slot" or something (whatever that means) and its expected that its contents change?

Comment: thanks, i mean the 12 is the unique identifier in the context.

Comment: Well then, don't reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think of the URL as the identifier (ID) for a resource that it points to.

If the underling resource is different, a different ID should be used.